# AD Group and Distribution Group with O365

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scripting, groups, microsoft-office-365

I have a O365 with Exchange, and a local AD.

I want to manage **distribution groups** and **distribution groups members** via **PS scripts** (that will run by scheduled task), that look users' AD attributes (don't know which attributes right now).

The script will be hosted in the local AD.

So If I want to manage distribution groups (DG), I can use PS to connect to my O365, and then manage DG. But I don't know If i'll be able to check AD users' attributes from a PS Session on O365 ?

So I'm wondering what is the best way to handle this.

Can I just manage DG from the AD without the need to connect to O365 Exchange ?

This means that I create AD Group, enable mail, and put users I want, in. Then, the replication will synchronize AD Group with O365 (with **DirSync** if I'm right).

Do these groups will be see as "Distribution Group" in O365 Exchange view ? And people will be able to email these DG ?
Or Do I have to do some stuff in O365 Exchange side ?

To be clear, question is : Can I create a DG from local AD server in PS (Create-Group), by setting the mail address (and others attributes I dont now yet), and then Exchange will see it as a good DG and I'll be able to send email to it ?

Feel free to ask for more details if needed. hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This means that I create AD Group, enable mail, and put users I want,
>   in. Then, the replication will synchronize AD Group with O365 (with
>   DirSync if I'm right).

That's pretty much it, yes.  There's plenty of resources out there covering the installation and setup of DirSync, and you may refer to [this table](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19901.dirsync-list-of-attributes-that-are-synced-by-the-windows-azure-active-directory-sync-tool.aspx) of attributes that are synced from on-premises AD to Office 365.  You can manually trigger a sync of dirsync by opening DirSyncConfigShell and running `Start-OnlineCoexistenceSync`

So you can create a DG on-premises, set the Mail and ProxyAddresses attributes and then DirSync will create a synchronised DG in O365.  This group will show up in the ECP > Groups, the same as a group which is created online.  However, since the group was created on-premises it must be managed on-premises (as the sync is one-way).  Trying to alter the attributes online will give you:

> The action 'Set-DistributionGroup', 'PrimarySmtpAddress', can't be
>   performed on the object 'IT-team' because the object is being
>   synchronized from your on-premises organization.

There is no need to mail-enable the DG, as DGs are mail-enabled by default at creation.

> To be clear, question is : Can I create a DG from local AD server in
>   PS (Create-Group), by setting the mail address (and others attributes
>   I dont now yet), and then Exchange will see it as a good DG and I'll
>   be able to send email to it ?

Broadly yes.  You'll have to use a PS cmdlet that actually exists though, ie `New-ADGroup` and specify `-GroupCategory Distribution`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just found the good article [here](https://smsagent.wordpress.com/tag/powershell-email-distribution-list/).

So I can do all the stuff I want with **local AD Server** : Create/Delete/Manage Groups.
But if I want the group I created to be a mail one, I have to use this command with **ExchangeManagementShell** (*EMS*) (or PS Session with O365 I guess) :

```
Enable-DistributionGroup -Identity MyDistributionGroup
```

Then If I use the AD to edit my group, I see updates on Exchange Admin Center (or ECP).

If someone have any ideas about how can I go through this need, because I don't want to depend of a PS Session to manage groups and members.

Edit : Do you think the best practise to be non-dependent of the connection, would be creating all groups I need, then, open a PSSession with O365, and just send all the `Enable-DistributionGroup` I need ? (I could save those commands in an array)

Comment: You don't need to use powershell to mail-enable the DG.  You can just create the DG on-premises and sync it up with Dirsync.  I'm surprised you haven't been able to test this yourself?

Comment: I did not have a test tenant within O365. I test it with my Exchange 2013. If I just created a mail-enabled DG, Exchange didn't see anything, but if I used the mail-enable cmdlet on the Exchanger server, I could see the DG on the ECP.

Comment: If you create a distribution group in on-premises AD , then run dirsync, the DG will show up in the Office 365 ECP.  Try it!

Comment: I must agree with you, since I have not any o365 tenant available anymore ... If you decide to post an answer with a little explanation about how to 'run dirsync', I would accept it as an answer with pleasure. (The project is ended, and I cannot use o365, i'm sorry)