# How to Convert Security Group to o365 Group?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

This is the reverse of [How to Convert o365 Group to Security Group?](https://serverfault.com/questions/819986/how-to-convert-o365-group-to-security-group)

This is a security group NOT a distribution list in which case I would've done [Upgrade distribution lists to Microsoft 365 Groups in Outlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/upgrade-distribution-lists?view=o365-worldwide)

Or perhaps I just convert "the security group" to "mail-enabled security group" first then do the "upgrade" I would accept that as an answer too.  Note this is Office 365 so I don't have Exchange installed locally otherwise I would just do this [Mail-enable or mail-disable existing security groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/recipients/mail-enabled-security-groups?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchserver-2019#mail-enable-or-mail-disable-existing-security-groups).

[How to mail-enable an existing Azure AD security group?](https://serverfault.com/questions/912746/how-to-mail-enable-an-existing-azure-ad-security-group?rq=1) tried to go through this intermediate step as well.  Though the current answer indicates this is not possible.

I basically want to retain the object ID since some external systems (specifically Sonarqube) uses the Object ID of my security group but I want the members of Developers (which are basically `Internal Developers` and `Contractors` groups) to be converted so I can use them with Microsoft Teams.

Is it possible?

I also don't have a local AD so I cannot avail of [AD Group and Distribution Group with O365](https://serverfault.com/questions/614408/ad-group-and-distribution-group-with-o365?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No can do unfortunately.

From Microsoft online documentation:

> Group type. You can't change the type of group after it's been
> created. To change the Group type, you must delete the group and
> create a new one.

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-settings-azure-portal#to-edit-your-group-settings

Comment: they really should "highlight" that quote

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to convert a security group to a 365 group

open an admin PowerShell

1. `install-module azureadpreview`
2. `connect-azuread`
3. Powershell script

```
#Type name of security group
$Group1 = "security group name"
#enter email alis without spaces or special car 
$mailname = "securitygroupname"
$group1ObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "Displayname eq '$group1'" | Select objectid -ExpandProperty ObjectID 
#Create new Office 365 group
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName $Group1 -MailNickname $mailname -GroupTypes "Unified" -MailEnabled $false -SecurityEnabled $True 
$group2 = Get-AzureADMSGroup -Filter "MailNickname eq '$mailname'" 
$membersGroup1 = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group1ObjectID -All $true
foreach($member in $membersGroup1)
{
    $currentuser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $member.ObjectId | select objectid
    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group2.ID -RefObjectId $currentuser.objectid
}
#press enter
Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group2.ID -All $true
```

credit MS support Donal Mooney

Comment: So to be clear. This script would create a new Microsoft 365 group and add the members from the existing group to the new group.

It will not convert a group to a different type. So please be careful to find any places the existing group may be referenced - e.g. Conditional Access, Intune policies etc...